# Cloning A Class

Tags: c#

I have two classes which contain the same fields, however one inherits some properties from somewhere else and the other does not.

I have created a generic list using the class "ZEUS_ResearchStocksHistory" , but then I need to clone all of the fields over to the other list "ZEUS_ResearchStocksHistoryWithExcel". I don't want to have to loop through each field in one list and populate the other, or write some sort of linq join, there must be a faster way?

The reason I can't use the same class in both instances is that when inheriting the ExcelReport function it adds additional fields which I do not want when I display this list in a data grid.

```
internal class ZEUS_ResearchStocksHistory
{
 public String Amendment { get; set; }
 public String AmendedBy { get; set; }
 public String Sedol { get; set; }
 public String Date { get; set; }
}

internal class ZEUS_ResearchStocksHistoryWithExcel : ExcelReport
{
 public String Amendment { get; set; }
 public String AmendedBy { get; set; }
 public String Sedol { get; set; }
 public String Date { get; set; }
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: You could implement the icloneable-interface in your class.

Comment: Why not just setup the the data grid to only display the fields you want?

Comment: "it adds additional fields which I do not want when I display this list in a data grid." This sounds like a display issue to me: if you could hide the unwanted columns from the data grid, would your problem be solved? If so, I'd strongly suggest searching for a solution to the display problem (they tend to be easier to solve and to understand).

Comment: *inheriting the ExcelReport function it adds additional fields which I do not want when I display this list in a data grid*: If you never want to see those properties and you have control over the `ExcelReport` class, consider adding the [`[Browsable(false)]`-attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute(v=vs.100).aspx) to those properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look at [automapper](http://automapper.org/)?

[example from codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper):

```
CustomerViewItem customerViewItem = 
   Mapper.Map<Customer, CustomerViewItem>(customer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/), which is designed to do exactly this. Automapper is up on NuGet.

http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/01/23/automapper-the-object-object-mapper/

You could do something as simple as:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ZEUS_ResearchStocksHistory, ZEUS_ResearchStocksHistoryWithExcel>();
var newObject = Mapper.Map<ZEUS_ResearchStocksHistory, ZEUS_ResearchStocksHistoryWithExcel>(oldObject);
```

Or, since you said you have a list, you could do:

```
var newList = oldList.Select(x => Mapper.Map<ZEUS_ResearchStocksHistory, ZEUS_ResearchStocksHistoryWithExcel>(x));
```